# SELECT COUNT query from two tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, count

I have this query

```
SELECT ( SELECT COUNT( answer ) FROM Voters WHERE answer = 'Yes' ), 
( SELECT COUNT(answer) FROM Voters WHERE answer = 'No' ), 
question, date, image
FROM Poll, Voters
WHERE Poll.poll_id = Voters.poll_id
```

and I am receiving this repeating result, how can I get a unique row? 
I want to achieve this:

```
Yes|No|Question|date|image
 2 |1 |  ques  |date| img
```

[image]

Comment: you are getting a 'cross-join' all vales are joined to all values ... solution use FROM TAB1 JOIN TAB2

Comment: So which is it: mysql or sql-server? Those are two very different database engines.

Comment: @SrinathGanesh No, he's not. It's matching for the join with the WHERE clause.

Comment: or simple FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 . since row heading is same in both tables ... then you will not need poll.vid = vot.vid

Comment: Are you sure the rows aren't unique already?  What are the contents of `image`?

Comment: Could you please update your question? Is your database SQL Server or MySQL? Please describe what columns are in your tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Yes",
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 'no'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "NO",
    question, date, image
FROM Poll p
INNER JOIN Voters v ON p.poll_id = v.poll_id
GROUP BY question, date, image
```

Comment: sorry, im a beginner here, I got this error, the text, ntext and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using is NULL or LIKE operator

Comment: Change the column to a `varchar(max)`

Comment: Oh: the image really is an image, isn't it? If that's so, you can't use that in the group by. You'll have to write the query without the image in the result set, and then use it as a subquery

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT distinct question, date, image,( SELECT COUNT( answer ) FROM Voters WHERE answer = 'Yes' ), 
    ( SELECT COUNT(answer) FROM Voters WHERE answer = 'No' )
    FROM Poll, Voters
    WHERE Poll.poll_id = Voters.poll_id
```

Comment: tnx, this works, but can I have another question,I get an error when i select distinct also the image, it says that the image datatype cannot be selected as distinct because it is not comparable, how can I solve this?